# Configuring sms centre for kannel

Tags: kannel

I have configured Kannel on windows. I tested it with a fake sms centre and it is working. What I require now is a message centre through which I am able to send sms to mobile. **However i am not sure how to get this sms centre information.**

1. Do i need to buy it from some network operators or are there any other free options available?
2. On the documentation of kannel, it says I can configure my own mobile to act as sms center. Can anyone tell me how to do so?
3. Is it possible to send free sms using kannel by any technique?

Comment: 1, you need to buy from network operator 2. yes, check the conf examples in kannel . 3. I doubt that

Comment: @Satya: There are no configuration examples given for how to use my mobile as smsc for kannel. Could you please provide a more elaborative answer on how to do the same? How should I connect my mobile to the server(By USB or something else)? How should i locate values for configuration parameters?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can connect to SMSC of mobile operator directly or to SMS gateway.
2. Yes, you can use any GSM-modem (or mobile handset) that supports standard AT commands and sending SMS in PDU mode.
3. This does not depend on Kannel.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Kannel to the SMSC of an SMS aggregator such as Infobip, Routesms etc.. You would need to register and purchase some credit units in order to send SMS.

You can also connect your GSM modem to Kannel and use it for sending SMS. However none of these is free. The Kannel user guide http://goo.gl/6Iqn4 would help in getting started with setting up the GSM modem.

You can also follow this link http://goo.gl/Y3jDa to have an idea of what configuring a GSM modem is like.